# OPC UA - String as Default

Tags: opc-ua

I'm working with a vendor which has delivered an OPC UA Client, which we have been using for some time now.

Three months ago we got into a situation where the data format somehow changed on all our readings.

For example value before, was 22,34, but suddenly this was displayed as 2234 after a server  Reboot.
Note: We use Danish format which has a comma as decimal point.

The last three months we have been troubleshooting this issue and today we received the answer, including the root cause.

Response from vendor:
As discussed on the phone after speaking with the developers they have advised that the issue seen is actually working as designed and that when an item is bad upon initial subscription it will have the data type of big string.

I have been unable to find the Answer whether or not this is According to the opa ua standard.

I find it very hard to believe that a Real should be converted to string, just because opc ua server is offline during subscription, because this could happen Daily All over the World

If some opc ua expect could help, then please let me know if the data type is changed to Big string by default whenever a subscription is made on an item that is bad.

Thx

Comment: Did you already use UaExpert to check the values? Additionally, it sounds really strange that the item will be set to big string. I don't think that this is according to the specification. But what you can do is check the OPC UA spec, it's free after register: https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture

Comment: We have not try to reproduce this using UaExpect, but this could be next step.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is 100% behavior of the application they delivered and has nothing to do with the spec.

Comment: The documentation is huge for this standard. What is the normal procedure when a client tries to subscribe to a server which is offline? - is it possible to start subscription when the server is offline?

Comment: No, you can't create a subscription when a server is not online to answer the request. Your original description made it sound like the server is online but the call to create monitored items fail, in which case there will be a reason associated with the failure, such as the NodeId doesn't exist (yet) or something like that. What you do in that case is up to the client application.